# why doesn't my delayed job work more than once when being triggered from a rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

given the delayed job worker,

```
class UserCommentsListWorker
  attr_accessor :opts
  def initialize opts = {}
    @opts = opts
  end

  def perform
    UserCommentsList.new(@opts)
  end

  def before job
    p 'before hook', job 
  end

  def after job
    p 'after hook', job
  end

  def success job
    p 'success hook', job
  end

  def error job, exception
    p '4', exception
  end

  def failure job
    p '5', job
  end

  def enqueue job
    p '-1', job
  end

end
```

When I run `Delayed::Job.enqueue UserCommentsListWorker.new(client: client)` from a rails console, I can get repeated sequences of print statements and a proper delayed job lifecyle even hooks to print including the feedback from the worker that the job was a success.

Including the same call to run the worker via a standard rails controller endpoint like;

```
include OctoHelper
include QueryHelper
include ObjHelper
include StructuralHelper

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if params['updateCache'] == 'true'
      client = build_octoclient current_user.octo_token
      Delayed::Job.enqueue UserCommentsListWorker.new(client: client)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm noticing that the worker will run and created the delayed job, but none of the hooks get called and the worker nevers logs the job as completed.

Notice the screenshot, [image]

Jobs 73,75,76 were all triggered via a roundtrip to the above referenced endpoint while job 74 was triggered via the rails console, what is wrong with my setup and/or what am I failing to notice in this process? I will stress that the first time the webserver hits the above controller endpoint, the job queues and runs properly but all subsequent instances where the job should run properly appear to be doing nothing and giving me no feedback in the process.

i would also highlight that i'm never seeing the failure, error or enqueue hooks run.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The long and the short of the answer to this problem was that if you notice, i was attempting to store a `client` object in the delayed job notification which was causing problems, so therefore, don't store complex objects in the job, just work with basic data ids `1` or strings `foo` or booleans `true` etc.  capisce?